# C# Unit Test framework for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

My director told me that there is a Unit Test framework for Visual Studio from Microsoft, but didn't know what the name of the tool was. Could anyone of you give a hint on it?

Answer (score 8):

MS Test - it's in the Professional version these days.

From what I remember, in 2005 it was only in the Team System editions (test and developer); as of 2008 it's in Professional.

Of course there are plenty of *other* unit test frameworks for .NET, such as [NUnit](http://nunit.org), [MbUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/) and [xUnit](http://xunit.codeplex.com/).

Comment: In 2010 it's in Professional (there is no Standard edition).

Also don't forget xUnit as an alternate framework.

Comment: Thanks for your answert. From wikipedia, I come across Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework. User can simply utilize it by inserting Attributes [TestClass()] [TestMethod()]. I'm looking for some concrete examples.

Comment: The link Colin posted (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625.aspx) gives a walk-through.

Comment: Technically, MS Test is the name of an executable that ships with Visual Studio that can run unit tests defined using the Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSTest) But most people just call the framework MS Test.

Answer (score 2):

It's called MSTest.  It's built into the Team Edition for Testers edition (and the higher level SKUs) of VS 2008.

In VS 2010, it's included in Visual Studio Professional.